# JDatabase: ¿Cómo hacer update sólo si el registro está vacío (NULL)?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla3

Al hacer un UPDATE mediante JDatabase, ¿cómo hacerlo si el registro inicialmente está vacío (NULL)?

He probado muchas formas de hacerlo, la última es esta, pero nada funciona, siempre me encuentro con que tengo un error de sintaxis en la query:

```
$columnas_a_actualizar = array(
    $db->quoteName('encuesta') . ' = ' . $db->quote('1'),
    $db->quoteName('fecha_encuesta') . ' = ' . $fecha_actual . ''
);

$condiciones = array(
    $db->quoteName('encuesta') . ' = IS NULL'
);

$query->update($db->quoteName('#__rsform_submissions'))->set($columnas_a_actualizar)->where($condiciones);
```

Comment: ¿Qué error aparece?

Comment: @Shaz, qué cosa tan rara, acabo de correr nuevamente el mismo script y ahora no sale ningún error, de hecho el resultado me devuelve 1, es decir, ok. Quién sabe, alguna especie de caché del servidor o algo. De cualquier forma sigue sin funcionar, a pesar que $result me devuelve 1, no se actualiza la base de datos. Cambié el **IS NULL** por **NULL**, y da lo mismo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no es relacionado directamnte con JDatabase, es en cambio un asunto de sintaxis de SQL.

No puedes usar el comparador `=` con `IS NULL` al tiempo:

```
$condiciones = array(
    $db->quoteName('encuesta') . ' IS NULL'
);
```

Aunque si tienes MySQL 5.7, puedes usar el nuevo operador `<=>`:

```
$condiciones = array(
    $db->quoteName('encuesta') . ' <=> NULL'
);
```

Comment: desgraciadamente no me funcionó como comentas. Pero sí me funciona si lo pongo así: $db->quoteName('encuesta') . ' = \'\' '